# how to make Java use all CPU power on a machine?

Tags: java, cpu

I sometimes write code in Java, and I noticed that sometimes it uses more than 100% CPU on a multicore machine. I am now running some code on a multicore machine that has 33 CPUs (Amazon's EC2), and I want to make my Java process use all CPUs available, so that it will have very high utilization of the machine. Is that possible, or is it left up to Java to decide when to use more than 100% CPU? I do not wish to change the code to use multithreading.

Comment: Utilizing more than 100% of available computational power is very impressive.  And it would be equally impressive to use all the computational power of a multicore machine despite the fact that you do not "wish to change the code to use multithreading."

Comment: @Kirk: I am reporting what 'top' reports - I am guessing it uses several CPUs in a multicore machine for the same Java process. This code never had any explicit mention of threads.

Comment: It is not possible for an algorithm in Java to leverage multiple threads without opting into a multithreaded solution via thread pools, etc.

Comment: so how should I interpret "top" reporting > 100% usage of CPU?

Comment: @kloop:  `top` reports > 100% usage due to threads using more than 100% of the CPU.  A single parent process may have many threads, thus leading to more than 100% usage.  Type 'H' to verify this for yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using multiple threads or processes (or something other than the one process running), you won't be able to achieve n*100% usage on a *n*-core machine.

The operating system decides to run each of your user programs on a single thread, unless a request for more is made.  Without that request, the OS will happily let you run your code in a single thread, potentially maxing out an entire CPU's cycles - but it leaves the others open.

Comment: Interesting. I guess there is some code that Java runs in parallel to the main execution of the code. Probably some management code of the virtual machine or something else in a separate thread.

Comment: @kloop GC runs on its own thread, as does Swing's EDT among others.

Answer (score 2):

If your program is not explicitly multi threaded (you don't start any thread yourself) then the only reason why it can utilize more than one core is because you are using some functionality of a library which ends up delegating work to a thread pool. Apparently you do not have much control over that so you can't make it work more necessarily.

In regards to utilizing all the CPUs in your S3 instance: You could start your program multiple times (e.g. 33 times if you have 33 CPUs). If that is not possible you will have to find out which part of your processing creates work on the thread pool and change your program so it does more of that (in parallel).